# Node.js redis@4 Upgrade: SocketClosedUnexpectedlyError: Socket closed unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, redis

I've got some *legacy code* that I'm upgrading from version 3 of the Node.js redis library to version 4 of the Node.js redis library.  The basic shape of the code looks like this

```
var redis = require('redis')
var client = redis.createClient({
    port: '6379',
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    legacyMode: true
})
client.connect()
client.flushall(function (err, reply) {
    client.hkeys('hash key', function (err, replies) {
      console.log("key set done")
      client.quit()
    })
})
console.log("main done")
```

When I run this code with redis@4.3.1, I get the following error, and node.js exits with a non-zero status code

```
main done
key set done
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

SocketClosedUnexpectedlyError: Socket closed unexpectedly
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/astorm/Documents/redis4/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:182:118)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Commander instance at:
    at RedisSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/astorm/Documents/redis4/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:350:14)
    at RedisSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at RedisSocket._RedisSocket_onSocketError (/Users/astorm/Documents/redis4/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:205:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/astorm/Documents/redis4/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:182:107)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12)
```

While in redis@3.1.2 it runs (minus the `client.connect()`) without issue.

I've been able to work around this by replacing `client.quit()` with `client.disconnect()`, but the actual code is a little more complex than the above example and I'd rather use the graceful shutdown of `client.quit` than the harsher "SHUT IT DOWN NOW" of `client.disconnect()`.

Does anyone know what the issue here might be? Why is redis@4 failing with a  `SocketClosedUnexpectedlyError: Socket closed unexpectedly` error.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same bug on a express js project,

```
  const redisClient = createClient({
    legacyMode: true,
    url: process.env.REDIS_URL,
  });
```

my error:

```
web.1 State changed from up to crashed
web.1 ERROR uncaughtException Socket closed unexpectedly
web.1 SocketClosedUnexpectedlyError: Socket closed unexpectedly
```

i change the code to

```
  const redisClient = createClient({
    legacyMode: true,
    url: process.env.REDIS_URL,
    pingInterval: 1000,
  });
```

the error disappear, i waited for an hour.
So pingInterval helped me to keep socket alive

Answer (score 2):

What I found so far is that after a while (keepAlive default is 5 minutes) without any requests the Redis client closes and throws an error event, but if you don't handle this event it will crash your application.
My solution for that was:

```
/* eslint-disable no-inline-comments */
import type { RedisClientType } from 'redis'
import { createClient } from 'redis'
import { config } from '@app/config'
import { logger } from '@app/utils/logger'

let redisClient: RedisClientType
let isReady: boolean

const cacheOptions = {
  url: config.redis.tlsFlag ? config.redis.urlTls : config.redis.url,
}

if (config.redis.tlsFlag) {
  Object.assign(cacheOptions, {
    socket: {
      // keepAlive: 300, // 5 minutes DEFAULT
      tls: false,
    },
  })
}

async function getCache(): Promise<RedisClientType> {
  if (!isReady) {
    redisClient = createClient({
      ...cacheOptions,
    })
    redisClient.on('error', err => logger.error(`Redis Error: ${err}`))
    redisClient.on('connect', () => logger.info('Redis connected'))
    redisClient.on('reconnecting', () => logger.info('Redis reconnecting'))
    redisClient.on('ready', () => {
      isReady = true
      logger.info('Redis ready!')
    })
    await redisClient.connect()
  }
  return redisClient
}

getCache().then(connection => {
  redisClient = connection
}).catch(err => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
  logger.error({ err }, 'Failed to connect to Redis')
})

export {
  getCache,
}
```

anyway... in your situation try to handle the error event

```
client.on('error', err => logger.error(`Redis Error: ${err}`))
```